# Is it possible to use a circle (SKShapeNode) as a mask in Sprite Kit?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, sprite-kit, skcropnode

I'm trying to create a circular mask in a Sprite Kit project. I create the circle like this (positioning it at the centre of the screen):

```
SKCropNode *cropNode = [[SKCropNode alloc] init];

SKShapeNode *circleMask = [[SKShapeNode alloc ]init];
CGMutablePathRef circle = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(circle, NULL, CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 50, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
circleMask.path = circle;
circleMask.lineWidth = 0;
circleMask.fillColor = [SKColor blueColor];
circleMask.name=@"circleMask";
```

and further down the code, I set it as the mask for the `cropNode`:

```
[cropNode setMaskNode:circleMask];
```

... but instead of the content showing inside a circle, the mask appears as a square.

Is it possible to use a `SKShapeNode` as a mask, or do I need to use an image?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After much swearing, scouring the web, and experimentation in Xcode, I have a really hacky fix.

Keep in mind that this is a really nasty hack - but you can blame that on Sprite Kit's implementation of `SKShapeNode`. Adding a fill to a path causes the following:

- adds an extra node to your scene
- the path becomes unmaskable - it appears 'over' the mask
- makes any non-`SKSpriteNode` sibling nodes unmaskable (e.g. `SKLabelNode`s)

Not an ideal state of affairs.

Inspired by [Tony Chamblee's progress timer](http://tonychamblee.com/2013/11/18/tcprogresstimer-a-spritekit-progress-timer/), the 'fix' is to dispense with the fill altogether, and just use the stroke of the path:

```
SKCropNode *cropNode = [[SKCropNode alloc] init];

SKShapeNode *circleMask = [[SKShapeNode alloc ]init];
CGMutablePathRef circle = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(circle, NULL, CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 50, 0, M_PI*2, YES); // replace 50 with HALF the desired radius of the circle
circleMask.path = circle;
circleMask.lineWidth = 100; // replace 100 with DOUBLE the desired radius of the circle
circleMask.strokeColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
circleMask.name=@"circleMask";

[cropNode setMaskNode:circleMask];
```

As commented, you need to set the radius to half of what you'd normally have, and the line width to double the radius.

Hopefully Apple will look at this in future; for now, this hack is the best solution I've found (other than using an image, which doesn't really work if your mask needs to be dynamic).

Answer (score 6):

Since I cannot use a **SKShapeNode** as mask I decided to convert it to a **SKSpriteNode**.

Here it is my Swift code:

```
let shape : SKShapeNode = ... // create your SKShapeNode
var view : SKView = ... // you can get this from GameViewController

let texture = view.textureFromNode(shape)
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
sprite.position = ...

cropNode.mask = sprite
```

And it does work :)

Comment: It looks like you will need to add an unused shape node to the scene. I suggest you look into creating a `UIImage` from a `CGPath` or a `UIBezierPath`. You can then generate a texture from the image.

Comment: Hi 0x141E, actually I am not adding ***shape*** (the SKShapeNode) to the scene. The only node that will be saved is ***sprite***.

Comment: This is a much better solution than the accepted one

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is impossible to use fill-colored shapenode in current Sprite-Kit realization. It's a bug, I think.

But!

You always can render the shape to texture and use it as mask!

For ex, let *edge* is SKShapeNode created before.

First, render it to texture **before** adding to view (in this case it will clean from another nodes)

```
SKTexture *Mask = [self.view textureFromNode:edge];
[self addChild:edge]; //if you need physics borders
```

Second,

```
SKCropNode *cropNode = [[SKCropNode alloc] init];
[cropNode setMaskNode:[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:Mask]];
[cropNode addChild: [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:rocksTiles size:CGSizeMake(w,h)]];
cropNode.position = CGPointMake(Mask.size.width/2,Mask.size.height/2);
//note, anchorpoint of shape in 0,0, but rendered texture is in 0.5,0.5, so we need to dispose it
[self addChild:cropNode];
```

Comment: And now some things are possible. (iOS 8.1): 
int deviceOSVersion= [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if (deviceOSVersion>=8.0)
        treeS.fillTexture=[SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"treeS"]];

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly awkward solution to this issue that I believe is slightly less nasty than any of the mooted hacks around this issue. Simply wrap your SKShapeNode in an SKNode. I haven't tested what kind of performance hit this might cause, but given that SKNode is non-drawing, I'm hoping it won't be too significant.

i.e.

```
let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
let maskNode = SKShapeNode(path: MyPath)
let wrapperNode = SKNode()
let cropNode = SKCropNode()

wrapperNode.addChild(maskNode)
cropNode.maskNode = wrapperNode
cropNode.addChild(background)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting alpha of mask node to .0 does the trick:

```
circleMask.alpha = .0;
```

EDIT:
Seems to work for Mac OS only.